# Getting issue wuth puppet module pcfens/filebeat

Tags: puppet, filebeat

I have an issue with the [pcfens/filebeat](https://forge.puppet.com/pcfens/filebeat) module.  I configured and deployed the filebeat to all my ngnix servers.  The filebeat service is up running, but it is not listening to the `ngnix` logs by the `ngnix.yml`.
It works as desired if I manually add the `input_type` property with the path to the ngnix logs in the main `filebeat.yml`, but how can I manage via puppet?

Comment: this is the module https://forge.puppet.com/pcfens/filebeat

Comment: You'll need to show your code.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with filebeat or with the module you are using, but from your description and the module docs, I am inclined to guess that you need to declare an instance of `filebeat::prospector` carrying the appropriate attributes.

Comment: class filebeat_wrap(){

      class { 'filebeat':
        outputs => {
        'logstash'     => {
        'hosts' => [
            '172.30.0.170:5044'
        ],
     'loadbalance' => true,
    },
  },

}

filebeat::prospector { 'nginx':
  paths    => [
    '/var/log/ngnix/*.log',
  ],
  doc_type => 'log',
}

}

Comment: this is my code.

Comment: this is my filebeat.yml :### Filebeat configuration managed by Puppet ###
---
shutdown_timeout: '0'
name: ip-172-30-0-139.cscloud.com
tags: []
fields: {}
fields_under_root: false
filebeat:
  registry_file: "/var/lib/filebeat/registry"
  config.prospectors:
    enabled: true
    path: "/etc/filebeat/conf.d/*.yml"
  shutdown_timeout: '0'
  modules: []
output:
  logstash:
    hosts:
    - 172.30.0.170:5044
    loadbalance: true
shipper: {}
logging: {}
runoptions: {}
processors: []
setup: {}
xpack: :undef

Comment: as you see this is the path to the ngnix.yml path: "/etc/filebeat/conf.d/*.yml", but it is not working. only if i edit the main filebeat.yml with input to ngnix path log its working. please assit me guyes

Comment: @ROIR, please do not post code in comments.  If you want to provide additional information, then it is usually best for you to edit that information into the question.